# Unexpected difference between 2 colors with colormath in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, colors

I have the following python code

```
from colormath.color_objects import sRGBColor, LabColor
from colormath.color_conversions import convert_color
from colormath.color_diff import delta_e_cie2000

color1_rgb = sRGBColor(0,0,0)
color2_rgb = sRGBColor(0,1,0)

# Convert from RGB to Lab Color Space
color1_lab = convert_color(color1_rgb, LabColor)
color2_lab = convert_color(color2_rgb, LabColor)

#Finding the difference
diff = delta_e_cie2000(color1_lab, color2_lab)
```

According to this link - http://colormine.org/delta-e-calculator/cie2000 I should be getting a difference of nearly 0.6 Whearas running this on my system using the colormath library returns a difference of nearly 82.76 Similar observations is seen for the color (255,255,255) and (255,254,254) Where am I wrong with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Scaling was required for converting the colours. Needed to add `is_upscaled=True` additional argument to sRGBColor function